# Permission denied when connection to ec2 intance, i have given the file permisson 400, but still not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I have created an ec2-intance on AWS. But when im trying to connect to it by using my `.pem` file, im getting error message: `Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)`. I have changed the permission to this file by `chmod 400 myfile.pm`.

This is the command i use to connect to my instance: `ssh -i ec2demo.pem ec2demo@ec2-35-158-140-25.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com`

I also searched for the issue on internet, and some people say i need to type `chmod 600 myfile.pem`. It still not works. Im using macOS Mojave, and the ssh client integrated. Do i need to install the AWS-CLI to make it works? Or should it work without AWS-CLI? And is it better to use ssh client from homebrew, or?

Thanx for help

Comment: Please show us the command you are using to connect. It should look similar to: `ssh -i key.pem ec2-user@1.2.3.4`

Comment: Have you created a Linux user on that instance called `ec2demo`, and copied the private half of the keypair to `/users/ec2demo/.ssh/authorized_keys`?

Comment: I have crated a instance called `ec2demo` yes, but what you mean by if i have copied the private half of the keypair to /users/ec2demo/.ssh/authorized_keys? im using macOS, in my `.ssh` folder, i have a `id.rsa, id_rsa.pub and known_hosts` file. When im using the command to connect the ec2-instance, its adding the instance to the list of known_host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When launching a new Amazon Linux instance on Amazon EC2, the public half of the keypair is copied to:

```
/users/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

You can then login to the instance using the private half of the keypair:

```
ssh -i key.pem ec2-user@1.2.3.4
```

(Or, you can use a DNS name instead of an IP address.)

It sounds like you have not logged into this instance yet, so make sure you login as `ec2-user` instead of `ec2demo`. The name of the instance does not impact the Linux user on the instance.

Comment: But if i name the instance to ec2demo, is not that the username before @ ? And then the dns after @?

Comment: I finally made it. The username before @dns , is default ec2-user, lol! But now i have learned it haha :) Thank you for the help!